# SQL Server Report Builder - How to grey out a parameter with multiple sub-reports?

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I have a main report which has three sub-reports. I am trying to grey out one of the parameter option when a certain report is selected. The reason I want to do that is because one of the sub report does not use this parameter. 
Here's the code I am using now. The parameter displaying the query result is @device.

```
    --When user select report 2, the parameter displays the device list from table2.
    IF @selectReport = 2
    BEGIN
       SELECT DISTINCT type
       FROM table2
    END

    --When user select report 3, the parameter displays the device list from table3.
    IF @selectReport = 3
    BEGIN
       SELECT DISTINCT type
       FROM table3
    END

    --When user select report 1. I want to grey out the parameter, but I could not do it. 
    --So I created the table contains NULL value. 
    --So, when the user select the report 1, the parameter will show only null value.

    IF @selectReport = 1
    BEGIN
       SELECT DISTINCT type
       FROM nullValueTable1
    END
```

I want it to be grey out when the report 1 is selected instead of show NULL on drop down list. Any idea???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't grey out the parameter. Unfortunately you can't hide the parameter either as the hidden property only takes `True` and `False`. What you are doing now might be the best you can do. However, you could try looking at [cascading parameters](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337169(v=sql.100).aspx), maybe you might be able to provide a slightly more user friendly value like "None" to the dropdown.